What can happen if everyone congregates at the back of a parked plane?
On a recent flight on an A320, after landing, when parked up at the gate, the cabin crew announced something along the lines of "Stairs will be at the front, please do not congregate at the back of the plane due to weight and balance calculations."
Why is this? What can happen?
For me, weight and balance is something I do before a flight relating to take-off performance etc. But obviously that was not the context here.

Related: Can passenger distribution cause a parked airliner to tip?

Loading up the back of a plane can indeed cause it to tip backwards and come to rest on its over-rotation skid. For this reason, some planes actually come with a detachable strut that holds up the tail end during loading. Once fully loaded and properly balanced, the plane's CG is fore of the mains and the strut is removed by the ground crew- hopefully before takeoff!
The critical tipover point (CG moves aft of the mains) will depend on the weight distribution of the cargo and fuel in the plane as it is loading humans. Note also that if the center of lift is fore of the mains, then a sudden wind gust may generate enough lift to rotate the fuselage onto its tail skid. Carnage and mayhem may result.
